# C# and Visual Studio Application Can't Dragging

Tags: visual-studio

My application a custom game launcher, looks like:

[image]

I can't dragging and when i click to icon in taskbar notting happens.

[image]

When i click to icon in taskbar, not coming to WindowsState.Minimize

Comment: Welcome - please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask because your post as it stands is not really going to get you any help.  You need to show minimum viable code for us to reproduce your issue

Comment: You're mentioning dragging and minimizing and I have no idea what your specific issue is. Please have a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question.

Comment: what code? i dont want code just need preferance https://snag.gy/BjeJyd.jpg

Comment: @HasanD. like I said, you haven't explained your problem very well so we don't understand what it is that you're having trouble with. If we don't understand what the problem is, we can't help you so you need to help us to understand by improving your question.

Comment: my problem;
when i click application icon on taskbar, app. not coming on screen and
i cant dragging application because i set border style = none.

Comment: Okay that's more helpful. I can't provide a solution for you, but I can tell you that WPF will allow you to create a borderless window that you can drag around. There's thousands of tutorials online that you can look at. I found [wpf-tutorial.com](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/) to be most useful

Comment: i dont want border